# How to reuse AngularJS templates on the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set up my first (proper) SPA AngularJS application which will have a couple of data tables filtering results for two different Leagues. At the moment I am able to display two tables for League A and League B but they display all results for both Leagues, since they are using the same template.

My template page includes a table with the following ng-repeat tag:

```
<tr ng-repeat="fixtures in items | filter:{ FixtureLeague: 'League A'}" id="fixtures_{{fixtures.Id}}">
```

Which is called from an ng-view div in the main page. I started looking at using a directive to specify/pass data into the template but I'm not sure how to actually make this work.

```
//Directive - Fixtures
FixturesApp.directive('cFixture', function () {
    return {
        template: '<tr ng-repeat="fixtures in items | filter: { FixtureLeague : "League A"}" id="fixtures_{{fixtures.Id}}">',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tree: '=ngModel'
        }
    };
});
```

Are there any examples of how you would reuse a template and pass different parameters to them or suggestions as to how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a value  to your directive:

`<c-fixture league='League A' ng-Model="..."></c-fixture>`

```
FixturesApp.directive(`cFixture`, function(){
    return {
        template: [
                    '<tr ng-repeat="fixtures in items" | filter: { FixtureLeague: league}',
                    'id="fixtures_{{fixtures.Id}} >"'
                  ].join(' '),

        replace: true,
        scope: {
            league: '@',
            items: '=ngModel'
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    }
})
```

There is a problem with your directive: you are creating an isolated scope `scope: {...}`, copying to it the value of `ngModel` to a property called `tree`. Anyway, you are not passing anywhere the value for `items`, so your ngRepeat won't work. I assumed in my implementation that you want to pass the collection of items as `ngModel`. Otherwise explain it and I will correct it.

As far as the different leagues are concerned, I pass the league to the filter as a string parameter to the `league` attribute. The `league` attribute is inserted into the scope as a string `league: @`.

Anyway, instead of using a filter for displaying two different league collections, I would create two different arrays on the model, because the filter will need to go through all leagues for all tables and it doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: Given your last point can you point me to an example or tutorial on how to use arrays within the model?

Comment: Let me prepare a fiddle.

Comment: Solved, working as expected. [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/LmxQU/6/)

Comment: Thanks link, that makes sense to me now. To extend this further, I am using a separate file as my template (list.html) - is it possible to pass variables to a file template?

Comment: In the sense that you are using a `templateUrl` for your directive? Of course, it will work anyway.